# Show Action Bar when user does not interact for some time in Android

Tags: android, android-actionbar, show, user-interaction

Hi in my android app I would like to hide the action bar on user interaction and show it again when the user has stopped interacting for some time. Now I already have the code for hiding the action bar:

```
    mViewPager.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            getActionBar().hide();
            return false;
        }
    });
```

I simply added an onTouchListener to my main view

But I do not know how to implement the `getActionBar.show();` method. How do i find out whether the user has been not interacting for, let's say, 2 seconds and thus implement `getActionBar().show();`?

Thanks in advance...

EDIT:

```
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        SystemClock.sleep(3000);

        if (isCancelled()) {
            break;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

This code is giving an error. `break can only be used inside loop or switch`. How to implement onCancelled()

Comment: By not interacted do you mean not touched the screen at all?

Comment: Yes, I mean exactly that.

Comment: You could set up an AsyncTask, put a sleep in there before showing the ActionBar, and if the user touches anything else cancel the task. See here for canceling task http://stackoverflow.com/a/10882600/993600 I'd put the isCancelled() check after the sleep and before showing the ActionBar

Comment: Should i use `SystemClock` or Thread.sleep (I'm guessing `SystemClock`)

Comment: I'm not particularly sure, I haven't had to use it before. I'd just Google it see which people say is the best to use.

Comment: @TomHart The `AsyncTask` works perfectly. I'm using `SystemClock`. Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ultimately you have to track the user interactions.
have a look at this post : 
[tracking-user-idle-time-within-the-app-in-android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14543842/tracking-user-idle-time-within-the-app-in-android)

By using this concept you can track the time and save in preference.

Now remaining logic is only for showing the actionbar if user is not active for some time interval (suppose 2seconds).

For that, You can create a `Thread` inside your `Activity` which **periodically** (in your case,at every 2seconds) checks last user-interaction time by calling `getElapsed()` method.if `getElapsed()` is greater than your desired time(2seconds).then show actionbar using `getActionBar().show()` method.

Comment: hi, I tried your method and it's easier to implement and more efficient. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking for a FullScreenActivity behaviour, like the one provided on the FullScreenActivity template. Read more about it: http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/templates.html#full-screen-activity

With this, you will have for free, a well tested code, with the behaviour: auto hiding the actionbar and showing it back when there's interaction.

Comment: yes but for me it's the other way round. I want to hide it on user interaction and show it on idle time

Answer (score 0):

You could set up an AsyncTask, put a sleep in there before showing the ActionBar, and if the user touches anything else cancel the task. [See here for canceling task](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10882600/993600). I'd put the isCancelled() check after the sleep and before showing the ActionBar

EDIT: What I'd do for your problem is

```
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    SystemClock.sleep(3000);

    if (!isCancelled()) {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                //Show the actionbar code here
            }
        });
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: I don't have any on hand, if you post your's in your original post I'll take a look see if I can spot the problem

Comment: See my post, try that.

Comment: I don't think there's any need to do that. When you do `AsyncTask.cancel(true)`, it goes to `onCancelled()` instead of `onPostExecute()`. All I needed to do was do `TimerTask.cancel()` before doing `TimerTask.execute` in my `onTouch()` method. Basically it's the same thing you posted. But Thanks, you've been a great help!!

Comment: Not a problem, glad to have helped :)

Comment: hey just one more question. Where do I put the `cancel(true);`?

Comment: I'd put it in any touch event where you want the ActionBar to stay hidden.